# Windows10 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

### Windows 10

When I tried install with below command

`python3 -m pip install jupyter`

getting an error:

`'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

- Path variable is setup
- pip is also working fine.

Comment: try using just python instead of python3

Comment: The Python executable is python.exe, not python3. You could figure this out yourself by looking in the Python folder to see if there is a *python3.exe* or *python3.bat* file in it.

Comment: I believe you only need to specify python3 when you're on a Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @emsimpson92

Issue resolved by using **python** instead of **python3**

Answer (score 0):

```
py -3 -m pip install jupyter
```

This works fine in the case of "python3 not recognized as an external or internal command error"